# Are Cassandra write consistency and hinted handoffs related?

Tags: cassandra

I was looking the Cassandra documentation about batches ([here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/batch_r.html)) when I noticed the following sentence:

```
When the rows in the batch have been successfully written and persisted (or hinted) 
the batchlog data is removed.
```

Does this ("or hinted") mean that, in the context of batch updates, writing a row to a replica node or writing an hinted handoff on the coordinator node is the same thing for Cassandra ?

If this is true, when an unavailable node returns alive, in case of delay in the hint delivery process, this can lead to eventual consistency, even if the statements in the batch have consistency ALL ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the context of a BATCH a write and a hinted handoff are both considered success (much like CL = ANY).

No, if you have read CL = ALL, then you'll get immediate consistency, at the expense of higher latency and lower availability. You'll have immediate consistency with CL = ALL even if a previously updated replica node is now out of date. In fact, all you would require for immediate consistency is for 1 replica node to have the most up to date partition.

The reason you get immediate consistency with read CL = ALL is that all replicas do an intra-node merge before sending their current partition to the coordinator. Then, the coordinator then does a coordinator merge to find the most up to date data among the partitions returned by the replica nodes.

Note:
intra-node merge and coordinator merge are my own terms. I use them to make it clear at what step within the read path a merge is happening.

Comment: Interesting. So, when using batch writes, the condition "write_consistency_level + read_consistency_level > replication_factor" does not guarantee strong consistency. You must ensure that read_consistency_level = replication_factor in order to achieve strong consistency, right?

Comment: I have to apologize. My answer is wrong. You can set the batch CL with `batch.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM);` or `batch.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.ALL);` in Java.

Comment: So, if you have write CL for the batch < replication factor, then hinted handoffs can be used in places of real writes. What I'm missing is: does the CL setting on statement level get overridden by the one on batch level? Does the behaviour change if you use LOGGED or UNLOGGED batches?

Comment: With batches, the write CL is set at the batch level, not the statement level (i.e. every statement has the same write CL).

Comment: Yes, the behavior changes for logged vs. unlogged batches.